# mysql key length limit on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos

Why does mysql not let me create table with a primary key column of size 767 on OSX?

It works fine on ubuntu.

I'm running mysql 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

What Table Engine are you using?

767 bytes is the max length for the primary key in InnoDB tables.

1000 bytes is the max for the MyISAM engine.

Maybe you are using InnoDB engine in your OSX Mysql

Comment: innodb... if I change it to 766 I get the same problem and it works on 767 in ubuntu

Comment: But what do you have as messagge? An error? Can you post here the messagge?

Comment: ERROR 1071 (42000): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: Are you creating te table using sql query? Or using the workbench? If you are creating the table with query can you post it?

Comment: Another question, the character set is the same? what are you using in OSX and what in ubuntu? If you are using UTF8 the length is 334(in MyISAM) or 252(InnoDB), because for 1 char the system use 3 bytes.